# tornado render argument in template

Tags: python, tornado

I feel like I hacked this into tornado and it is in poor form.  The goal was to get an error message down into a template.  This error message would only need to be within one handler (responsible for that same page).

The template line:

```
{% if errormsg is not None %}
<div class="alert-warning">{{ errormsg }}</div>
{% end %}
```

The relevant handler section:

```
if auth:
  self.set_current_user(username)
  self.redirect(self.get_argument("next",u"/"))
else:
  self.errormsg = "Login Failed"
  self.render("login.html", errormsg=self.errormsg)
```

At this point I was getting global namespace error messages on the page when errormsg was not set to something.

```
NameError: global name 'errormsg' is not defined
```

The workaround I found was to muck around with the global render function within my BaseHandler (I do not like this one bit):

```
def render(self, template, **kwargs):
  if hasattr(self, 'errormsg'):
    kwargs['errormsg'] = self.errormsg
  else:
    kwargs['errormsg'] = None
  super(BaseHandler, self).render(template, **kwargs)
```

This basically adds the errormsg to every render now.  Is there a correct way to do this that doesn't mess with the global render function?

Thanks!

---

Edit:

Because what I'm actually trying to do is pass different/multiple, non-standard kwargs parameters into inherited handlers, I actually really think I was looking for a better way to test, in this case errormsg, within the template context.

```
{% if 'errormsg' in globals() %}
```

This still feels pretty hacked into place since this issue is the first time globals actually showed up at all while working with tornado.

I do like extending render for setting kwargs default values for all inherited handlers (what it is actually for).  I think this may also be similar to how self.current_user works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overriding `render()` is officially supported, but it's a bit cleaner to override `get_template_namespace` instead: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_template_namespace

Or, if `errormsg` is an attribute of the `RequestHandler`, you can just access `handler.errormsg` in the template - the `handler` variable is always set to the current RequestHandler.

Comment: Ohhh, overriding get_template_namespace is going to make some of my apps much cleaner. Thanks!